# Capturar a data de criação do arquivo

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp

Estou criando um painel de controle em *jsp* para mostrar as atualizações dos arquivos em Excel de uma determinada pasta na rede.

**Problema:** Tenho vários programas em SAS que estão programados para atualizar diariamente, e gerar os arquivos na pasta. Porém, às vezes, a programação não executa conforme o esperado e o arquivo  fica desatualizado.

**Objetivo:** Identificar no painel tudo que não está atualizado e rodar o programa manualmente.

A ideia que tive é utilizar esta fórmula, mas não sei como capturar a data do arquivo em *jsp*:

```
Se dt_arquivo = hoje() campo recebe "Atualizado" senão "Não "Atualizado"
```

Comment: Coloque o trecho do código da sua view jsp e do controller(servlet), correspondente ao erro, ficaria melhor para entender sua necessidade.

Answer (score -1):

Cria um método e depôs salva as informação no banco:

```
public InformacaoArquivo  verificarDataModificacao(String nomeArquivo) throws IOException {
         Path file  =  new File("C:\\text\\"+nomeArquivo).toPath();
         BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

         InformacaoArquivo info = new InformacaoArquivo(attr.creationTime().toString(), attr.lastAccessTime().toString(), attr.lastModifiedTime().toString() ); 

         System.out.println("hora de criação: " + attr.creationTime());
         System.out.println("último  acesso: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
         System.out.println("última  modifição: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
        return info;     
    }


public class InformacaoArquivo {

  private String horaCriacao;
  private String ultimoAcesso;
  private String  ultimaModificao;

  public InformacaoArquivo(String horaCriacao, String ultimoAcesso, String ultimaModificao) {
      this.horaCriacao = horaCriacao;
      this.ultimoAcesso = ultimoAcesso;
      this.ultimaModificao = ultimaModificao;
}
```

Você pode usar em uma class e chama no seu `jsp` ou se você te ver usando um `controller` pode fazer la também e passa para jsp

Depois você pode converter as data para `Date` e fazer comparação. todos os importes tem que ser do pacote `java.nio.*`;